# OpsWorks (Chef) before_symlink callback not working

Tags: chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I am trying to add a `before_symlink` callback to a custom `deploy` Chef recipe, for use on AWS OpsWorks. I’m using the Chef 11 setup, so Amazon’s own receipes take care of 95% of what’s going on.

I’m getting a `Recipe Compile Error`:

```
NoMethodError
-------------
No resource or method named `before_symlink' for `Chef::Recipe "deploy"'
```

I am still learning Chef so I’m not clear what’s causing this. I’ve called `include_recipe 'deploy'` at the beginning of the custom recipe, and [Amazon’s own custom deploy recipe](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/release-chef-11.10/deploy/definitions/opsworks_deploy.rb) seems to work similarly.

Here’s my recipe:

```
include_recipe 'deploy'

node[:deploy].each do |application, deploy|

  if (deploy[:application_type] != 'rails') || (application != 'backscratchers')
    Chef::Log.debug("Skipping deploy::rails application #{application} as it is not a Rails app")
    next
  end

  before_symlink do
    directory "#{release_path}/tmp" do
      mode 0770
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: I managed to get this working by wrapping the `before_symlink` block in a `deploy` block, but this _also_ deploys the application a second time! So I’m still not sure how to add a callback to the AWS deploy recipe...

Comment: Seems like maybe the only ways to do this are 1) rewrite the `deploy` recipe entirely, adding the new bits or 2) add a `config/deploy/before_symlink.rb` file to the app itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `before_symlink` block has to actually go inside `deploy` or `deploy_revision` recipe. It is unrelated to Amazon's `deploy` cookbook/recipe.

That said, I don't not recommend using the `deploy` resource anymore as it is overcomplicated for most needs. Check out https://github.com/poise/application_examples/ for examples of a more Chef-style application deployment.

Comment: Thanks for this, I’ve done some more reading and I’ll look into using OpsWorks’ Chef 12 offering, with 3rd party cookbooks like the poise ones you’ve pointed out.